# Problema con tableView: no se puede convertir el tipo 'System.Data.DataTable' a 'AppKit.INSTableViewDataSource

Tags: c#

Cuando intento que se muestren los datos de mi base de datos en un `tableView` me salta ese error y si lo convierto en NSTableViewDataSource me salta un `System.ExceptionCatch`. Es la primera vez que me pasa este error. Si alguien sabe como solucionarlo o cree de que puede ser por favor comentádmelo.

Perdón por no subirlo en formato texto y gracias por las sugerencias. Aquí esta:

```
public partial class ViewController : NSViewController
{
    dataBase sql = new dataBase();



    public ViewController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
    {

    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        tableView.DataSource = sql.MostrarDatos();
         // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    public override NSObject RepresentedObject
    {
        get
        {
            return base.RepresentedObject;
        }
        set
        {
            base.RepresentedObject = value;
            // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }



}
```

Y este es el error:

> Error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.DataTable' to 'AppKit.INSTableViewDataSource'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) (CS0266)

Y aqui el codigo de MostrarDatos:

```
 public class dataBase
{



    private MySqlConnection cnx = new MySqlConnection("server = 127.0.0.1; database=Facturas; Uid=root;pwd=pablo_37;");
    private DataSet ds;

    public void ProbarConexion()
    {

        var alert = new NSAlert();
        try
        {

            cnx.Open();
            alert.InformativeText = "Conectado";
            alert.RunModal();


        }
        catch (Exception r)
        {

            alert.MessageText = r.Message;
            alert.RunModal();
        }
        finally { cnx.Close(); }



    }

    public DataTable MostrarDatos()
    {


        cnx.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select * from Factura", cnx);
        MySqlDataAdapter ad = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        ds = new DataSet();
        ad.Fill(ds, "Factura");
        return ds.Tables["Factura"];


    }

 }
```

Para la aplicación estoy usando visual studio con Xcode y mysql por si alguien ya ha trabajado con ello y sabe algo del problema u otra solución para poder hacer consultas de las tablas a través de ellas. Lo aplicación es de escritorio. Gracias por vuestra ayuda y comentarios de antemano.

Comment: Necesitamos ver el código de `MostrarDatos`

Comment: No pasa nada. Siento no poder ser de mas ayuda. Si le doy a corrección rápida y le doy a convertir en NSTableViewDataSource me desaparece el error pero al depurarlo me salta un System.InvalidCatchException.No se si el problema es del primer error o del segundo :(

Answer (score 0):

La vista debería ser UIViewController , no NSViewController
El datasource de la tabla tiene que ser en minúsculas. Tienes que asignarle un algo que cumpla el protocolo de datasource de la TableView, no te vale con le enchufo la conexión de la base de datos y el tiene que saber todo. Así pues:

```
tableView.datasource = sql
```

y en la clase database tienes que implementarle en datasource de tabla con sus métodos:

```
extension database: UITableViewDataSource {
//metodos del UITableViewDataSource
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       //te tendrás que buscarte la vida para saber que celda devuelves

   }

  func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
     //tendras que buscar en la BD cuantas secciones tienes y devolverlo
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
      //tendras que buscar en la BD cuantas celdas hay en cada sección
  }
```

Comment: Creo que me puso NSViewController por que tengo que poner los controles en Xcode y me lo creo asi de forma predefinida al ser una app desktop. Al cambiar NSViewController a UIViewController salta error.